# How to create a single date variable from separate month and year variables in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a data set in which the date of an event is represented by two variables: month of the event and the year of the event. I would like to turn these two variables into a single variable, preferably formatted as a date/time variable. How would the syntax for doing this in SPSS look?

NB. I don't have a variable specifying which day (1-31) of the month a date is (and the day isn't important either). I was thinking of either just using a date format that only include the month and year, or specifying that all events happened on the first of each month.

Image illustrating how the variables look:

[image: Image illustrating how the variables look]

Image illustrating how the new date variable should look
[image: Image illustrating how the new date variable should look]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the menu:

```
Transform/Date and Time Wizard/Create a Date/time variables from...
```

Then select your `Month` variable to the Month field, `Year` variable to Year field

Press `Next`

Put a name into the 'Result Variable` field (e.g.: "MonthYear")

From the "Output format" choose whichever format you want (e.g.: "mmm yyyy")

I would suggest to "Paste" the syntax, in case you need it later ;)

Press Finish and you will get a syntax looking like this (based on the above inputs):

```
COMPUTE  MonthYear=DATE.DMY(1, Month, Year).
VARIABLE LABELS  MonthYear "".
VARIABLE LEVEL  MonthYear (SCALE).
FORMATS  MonthYear (MOYR8).
VARIABLE WIDTH  MonthYear(8).
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: That was much easier than I had expected. Thanks for the answer, and for posting the syntax!

Comment: If the answer did the job, please mark it as "accepted", so others can now it is the correct answer. that's the spirit of stack overflow ;)